# Load and Save the values to and from ComboBox, NumericUpDown, HexUpDown in C#

Tags: c#, save, load, tabcontrol

My Windows Application consists of various Settings which mainly include the data in numeric form(both decimal and Hex) and some comboBox .
When the user gives input in these box and  when Save button is pressed the settings should be saved(any simple format or any file can work, I am not bound to any particular types) and when Load button is pressed the respective values should be displayed in respective boxes.
What could be the easiest way to perform this.

P.S : My design is in the form of tabcontrol and the boxes are on different tabpages, and save should save data from all tabpages in one file.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to save it in Application Settings where its already there for you:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName = "Setting Value";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

you can find [more info about it in here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp).

Another way would be just saving your settings in a text file and loading them (Not Recommended).

```
string Settings = "SomeComboBoxValue = 1\r\n" +
                  "SomeButtonValue = OK" //goes on like this
```

To Save:

```
File.WriteAllText("settings.txt", Settings);
```

To Load:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("settings.txt");
foreach(string setting in lines)
{
     string[] s = setting.Split('=');
     switch(s[0].Trim())
     {
          case "SomeComboBoxValue":
              ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(s[1].Trim()); break;
          case "SomeButtonValue":
              Button1.Text = s[1].Trim(); break;
         //goes on like this
     }
}
```

Comment: Hello Ashkan, 
What about Load?

Comment: It is already loaded by default you just have to read it like: `Button1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName`

Comment: To create settings, in your project (in solution explorer) find `Properties > Settings` and create your settings there

Comment: I am sorry to bother , but can you tell me where to find it in Sharp Develop

Comment: I'm sorry I have not used SharpDevelop